# foverlaps and within in data.table

Tags: r, data.table, time-series

Have 2 tables

dums:

```
start   end 10min 

2013-04-01 00:00:54 UTC 2013-04-01 01:00:10 UTC 0.05

2013-04-01 00:40:26 UTC 2013-04-01 01:00:00 UTC 0.1

2013-04-01 02:13:20 UTC 2013-04-01 04:53:42 UTC 0.15

2013-04-02 02:22:00 UTC 2013-04-01 04:33:12 UTC 0.2

2013-04-01 02:26:23 UTC 2013-04-01 04:05:12 UTC 0.25

2013-04-01 02:42:47 UTC 2013-04-01 04:34:33 UTC 0.3

2013-04-01 02:53:12 UTC 2013-04-03 05:27:05 UTC 0.35

2013-04-02 02:54:08 UTC 2013-04-02 05:31:15 UTC 0.4

2013-04-03 02:57:16 UTC 2013-04-03 05:29:32 UTC 0.45
```

maps: start and end are 10 minute interval blocks spanning 2013-4-1 00:00:00 to 2013-04-04

I want to add the column 3 of dt1 to map as long as the start and end time are within the 10 minute blocks and keep appending the columns

ideally the output should be

```
start              end            10min

4/1/2013 0:00:00 4/1/2013 0:10:00   0.05  0

4/1/2013 0:10   4/1/2013 0:20   0.05     0

4/1/2013 0:20   4/1/2013 0:30   0.05    0

4/1/2013 0:30   4/1/2013 0:40   0.05    0

4/1/2013 0:40   4/1/2013 0:50   0.05    0.01

4/1/2013 0:50   4/1/2013 1:00   0.05    0.01
```

I tried

```
setkey(dums,start,end)

setkey(map,start,end)

foverlaps(map,dums,type="within",nomatch=0L)
```

I keep getting the error:

```
Error in foverlaps(map, dums, type = "within", nomatch = 0L) :   All entries in column start should be <= corresponding entries in column end in data.table 'y'
```

Any pointers or alternative approaches?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

The error message

> All entries in column start should be <= corresponding entries in column end in data.table 'y'

is probably caused by a typo in the dataset.

```
dums[start > end, with = TRUE]
```

returns `4` and row 4 of dums is:

> ```
>                  start                 end min10
> 1: 2013-04-02 02:22:00 2013-04-01 04:33:12   0.2
> ```

After changing `start` to `2013-04-01 02:22:00` OP's code runs fine.

However, to achieve the expected output the result of `foverlaps()` needs to be reshaped from long to wide format.

This can be done in two ways:

```
dcast(foverlaps(map, dums, nomatch = 0L), i.start + i.end ~ min10, 
      value.var = "min10")
```

> ```
>                  i.start               i.end 0.05 0.1 0.15 0.2 0.25 0.3 0.35 0.4 0.45
>   1: 2013-04-01 00:00:00 2013-04-01 00:10:00 0.05  NA   NA  NA   NA  NA   NA  NA   NA
>   2: 2013-04-01 00:10:00 2013-04-01 00:20:00 0.05  NA   NA  NA   NA  NA   NA  NA   NA
>   3: 2013-04-01 00:20:00 2013-04-01 00:30:00 0.05  NA   NA  NA   NA  NA   NA  NA   NA
>   4: 2013-04-01 00:30:00 2013-04-01 00:40:00 0.05  NA   NA  NA   NA  NA   NA  NA   NA
>   5: 2013-04-01 00:40:00 2013-04-01 00:50:00 0.05 0.1   NA  NA   NA  NA   NA  NA   NA
>  ---                                                                                 
> 311: 2013-04-03 04:40:00 2013-04-03 04:50:00   NA  NA   NA  NA   NA  NA 0.35  NA 0.45
> 312: 2013-04-03 04:50:00 2013-04-03 05:00:00   NA  NA   NA  NA   NA  NA 0.35  NA 0.45
> 313: 2013-04-03 05:00:00 2013-04-03 05:10:00   NA  NA   NA  NA   NA  NA 0.35  NA 0.45
> 314: 2013-04-03 05:10:00 2013-04-03 05:20:00   NA  NA   NA  NA   NA  NA 0.35  NA 0.45
> 315: 2013-04-03 05:20:00 2013-04-03 05:30:00   NA  NA   NA  NA   NA  NA 0.35  NA 0.45
> ```

or, more in line with OP's expected result:

```
dcast(foverlaps(map, dums, nomatch = 0L), i.start + i.end ~ rowid(i.start), 
      value.var = "min10")
```

> ```
>                  i.start               i.end    1    2  3  4  5
>   1: 2013-04-01 00:00:00 2013-04-01 00:10:00 0.05   NA NA NA NA
>   2: 2013-04-01 00:10:00 2013-04-01 00:20:00 0.05   NA NA NA NA
>   3: 2013-04-01 00:20:00 2013-04-01 00:30:00 0.05   NA NA NA NA
>   4: 2013-04-01 00:30:00 2013-04-01 00:40:00 0.05   NA NA NA NA
>   5: 2013-04-01 00:40:00 2013-04-01 00:50:00 0.05 0.10 NA NA NA
>  ---                                                           
> 311: 2013-04-03 04:40:00 2013-04-03 04:50:00 0.35 0.45 NA NA NA
> 312: 2013-04-03 04:50:00 2013-04-03 05:00:00 0.35 0.45 NA NA NA
> 313: 2013-04-03 05:00:00 2013-04-03 05:10:00 0.35 0.45 NA NA NA
> 314: 2013-04-03 05:10:00 2013-04-03 05:20:00 0.35 0.45 NA NA NA
> 315: 2013-04-03 05:20:00 2013-04-03 05:30:00 0.35 0.45 NA NA NA
> ```

Note that the parameter `type = "within"` has been skipped for brevity.

#### Data

```
# corrected
dums <- fread(
  " 2013-04-01 00:00:54 UTC 2013-04-01 01:00:10 UTC 0.05
    2013-04-01 00:40:26 UTC 2013-04-01 01:00:00 UTC 0.1
    2013-04-01 02:13:20 UTC 2013-04-01 04:53:42 UTC 0.15
    2013-04-01 02:22:00 UTC 2013-04-01 04:33:12 UTC 0.2
    2013-04-01 02:26:23 UTC 2013-04-01 04:05:12 UTC 0.25
    2013-04-01 02:42:47 UTC 2013-04-01 04:34:33 UTC 0.3
    2013-04-01 02:53:12 UTC 2013-04-03 05:27:05 UTC 0.35
    2013-04-02 02:54:08 UTC 2013-04-02 05:31:15 UTC 0.4
    2013-04-03 02:57:16 UTC 2013-04-03 05:29:32 UTC 0.45"
)
dums <- dums[, .(start = as.POSIXct(paste(V1, V2, V3)),
         end = as.POSIXct(paste(V4, V5, V6)),
         min10 = V7)]
setkey(dums, start, end)
ts <- seq(as.POSIXct("2013-04-01 00:00:00 UTC"),
          as.POSIXct("2013-04-04 00:00:00 UTC"),
          by = "10 min")
map <- data.table(start = head(ts, -1L), end = tail(ts, -1L),
                   key = c("start", "end"))
```

Comment: Using `head` and `tail` to create the start / end is genius. I had no idea you could do that.

Answer (score 0):

That's a good catch with the POSIXct time being off for 1 row. I feel super silly to have glossed over such an error in the input data.

The ultimate goal is to have 3 column variables : YYYY-DD-MM ; start time (POSIXCt), end time (POSIXCt). 
The start and end time being 10 minute windows. 
The number of days is 365. So effectively looking at 365 * 144 (10 minute slices for a day). The catch is I have 450k rows of "dums" data and the min10 is not evenly spaced discrete intervals, it is a continuous data. If I have to aggregate (sum,means,sd etc) , is there any way to use the dcast + aggregate +foverlaps within+ grouping? I can do with a for loop just placing the min10 value from start to end but it looks super time consuming and inefficient.

The output would be

```
  5: 2013-04-01 00:40:00 2013-04-01 00:50:00 0.15
  ---
  311: 2013-04-03 04:40:00 2013-04-03 04:50:00 0.80 

  map <- data.table(start = head(ts, -1L), end = tail(ts, -1L),
               key = c("start", "end"))
    # plus do something on the lines
  dums[, .(count=.N, sum=sum(min10)), by = ID1]
```